# N-tiered web app to save a role

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ninject

My project manager is saying that there are many bad things in my code, but they are not helping me to correct it. Can you please specify the bad things they mean?

I have 7 projects in my solution that work together to save a role to the database. Here are the details:

**Project - 1 - Object Model(Class Library Project) - Only declaring the Class Properties**

```
public class OM_Role
{
    [DisplayName("Role ID"), Key]
    public Int16 RoleID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Role Name"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter role")]
    public String Role { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Is Activated")]
    public Boolean IsActivated { get; set; }
}
```

**Project - 2 - IDAL(Class Library Project) - Declaring the Interface methods**

```
public interface IRole
{
    Task<String> Save(OM_Role role);
}
```

**Project - 3 - Definition of Save Role Method**

```
public class DAL_Role : IRole
{
    public async Task<String> Save(OM_Role role)
    {
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(
            TransactionScopeOption.Required,
            new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted },
            TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {

            using (var roleContext = new DatabaseTables())
            {
                var data = await roleContext.tblRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
                i => i.RoleID == role.RoleID);
                if (data != null)
                {
                    data.Role = role.Role;
                    data.IsActivated = role.IsActivated;
                }
                else
                {
                    role.IsActivated = false;
                    roleContext.tblRoles.Add(role);
                }
                await roleContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                transaction.Complete();
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Project - 4 - WebAPI for calling the DAL Layer through IRole using Ninject**

```
public class roleAPIController : ApiController
{
    IRole _role;
    public roleAPIController(IRole role)
    {
        _role = role;
    }

    public roleAPIController()
    {
    }

    [Route("api/v1/SaveRole"), HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Save([FromBody] OM_Role role)
    {
        var result = await _role.Save(role);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { ErrorMessage = result });
    }
}
```

**Project - 5 - BLL(Class Library Project) - This calls the Web API**

```
internal class RoleResponse
{
    public String ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public OM_Role result { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
}

public class BLL_Roles : IRole
{
    public async Task<string> Save(OM_Role role)
    {
        try
        {
            var url = "api/v1/SaveRole";
            String URI = String.Format("{0}{1}", "APIDomainName", url);    
            var postData = new OM_Role();
            postData.IsActivated = role.IsActivated;
            postData.Role = role.Role;
            postData.RoleID = role.RoleID;    
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();    
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject
  (postData));    
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(URI, content);    
            /*     Retrieve the data from API    */
            string responseBody = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var result =
           ((RoleResponse)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoleResponse>(responseBody));    
            return result.ErrorMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

**Project - 6 - Presentation Layer that calls BLL using Ninject**

```
[LoginAuthentication, AdminAuthorization]
public class roleController : Controller
{
    IRole _role;
    public roleController(IRole role)
    {
        _role = role;
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("SaveRole")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Save(OM_Role objrole)
    {
        var data = await _role.Save(objrole);
        return Json(new { Success = String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) });
    }
}
```

**Project - 7 - Code First Database Creation Entity FrameWork**

```
public class DatabaseTables : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseTables()
        : base("Freelancer")
    {
    }

    public virtual IDbSet<OM_Role> tblRoles { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        RoleTable(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void RoleTable(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var roleModel = modelBuilder.Entity<OM_Role>();
        roleModel.Property(x => x.RoleID)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        roleModel.Property(x => x.Role).IsRequired().IsVariableLength().HasMaxLength(50);
        roleModel.Property(x => x.IsActivated).IsRequired();
        roleModel.ToTable("tblRole");
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me get this straight. You have 7 separate *projects* or you have 7 separate *files*?

Comment: @RubberDuck: There are 7 different Projects

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the project manager is telling you that is bad?

Comment: @EthanBierlein: Sir, they just told that to remove the unnecessary code and to use the best coding conventions. Unfortunately they are not able to suggest the good things they want to see. I think, may be because they are busy.

Comment: Okay. One more question. (Two actually). Is there more code in these projects? Did someone specify this design for you, or did you come up with this high level design yourself? (Not the code, I know you wrote the code, I mean the architecture.)

Comment: @RubberDuck: Sir, Nobody suggested me. I divided them in 7 parts so that I could avoid intermixing the code from each other.

Comment: @RubberDuck: Sir, Will you personally like to recommend my Architecture or there are some unnecessary project creations ? I am ready to change the code completely, I am serious. I am ready to do it. or Kindly suggest if I can change the Architecture to make it more comprehensive and flexible

Comment: You seem to have way too much on the line for me to want to say much. I will say that having 7 projects for this seems like overkill. What was the simplest thing that would have *worked*? Probably a project containing your MVC app and one containing your WebApi. (Plus a test project [maybe two. *maybe*]).

Comment: @RubberDuck :  Sir, I gave this for only Role Management. There are almost 48 classes. Total 13 modules in the live code.I merely gave an example of Role class. I did this to keep the code clean. Keeping only 3 projects will mix the things and new developer may not be able to do the new things quickly, I think.

Comment: Ahhh. Yeah. That's why I asked if there was more code earlier. Never mind me.

Comment: @RubberDuck: Sir, I can share the source code. But there is no provision to attach the files that can be downloaded on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Pankaj Sir, I wasn't asking for you to add it. I was trying to determine if all these projects were overkill. They're not from the way you describe it.

Comment: @RubberDuck: I will never say that I am 100% sure that my architecture is good. But imagine if our client says to reuse the code for Android App...then I can reuse Web API 2.0, which is already connected with DAL and if tomorrow somebody says to change code for  Oracle or MySQL then it should be done without disturbing other layers. Because this will make sure that while doing Unit Testing, impact is not on 100% code. It's on like 20% of the code as per the current architecture.

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Naming conventions.**

In C#, types are named using PascalCase. Rename:

- `OM_Role` to `OmRole`
- `DAL_Role` to `DalRole`
- `rolesAPIController` to `RolesApiController`
- and so on

The same goes for properties - so `tblRoles` should be named `TblRoles`

**Coding Style**

You could mark your private field `_role` `readonly`. People often also explicitly mark them as `private` though it's not entirely needed.

The `IRole` type doesn't really represent a role, does it? The name seems misleading. I think `IRoleRepository` would be a better fit.

Why does `roleAPIController` have a parameterless constructor? Using that constructor would result in `NullRefenceException`s being thrown, since `_role` would be unassigned.

This cast is unnecessary:

```
var result = ((RoleResponse)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoleResponse>(responseBody));
```

You should wrap the usage of `IHttpClient` in a using statement to ensure proper resource cleanup:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    ...
}
```

**Exceptions**

Regarding `BLL_Roles.Save`: Catching all exceptions is usually regarded as a bad idea. I'm not saying this is the case, but consider catching the specific exceptions you expect to happen, e.g. `HttpRequestException`, `JsonException`, etc.

<s>Why does the `IRole.Save` method return a `Task<string>` if the string is always empty? Why not just `Task`? Similarly, your `roleController` checks if the string is null: `String.IsNullOrEmpty(data)`, this seems redundant.</s>

Also, returning a empty/non-empty string to signal that something went wrong does not seem right. Surely, if the API call fails, that would be an exceptional scenario, would it not? Consider letting the exception bubble up to the controller, where the error can be handled. Then, change the `IRole.Save` return type from `Task<string>` to simply `Task`.

This is how I'd report errors:

Web Api:

```
public interface IRole
{
    Task Save(OmRole role);
}


public class DalRole : IRole
{
    public async Task Save(OmRole role)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class RoleApiController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/v1/roles"), HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async IHttpActionResult Save([FromBody] OM_Role role)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _role.Save(role);
            return OK();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log exception
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

MVC App:

```
public class BllRole : IRole
{
    public async Task Save(OmRole role)
    {
        var url = "api/v1/roles";
        String URI = String.Format("{0}{1}", "APIDomainName", url);    
        var postData = new OmRole();
        postData.IsActivated = role.IsActivated;
        postData.Role = role.Role;
        postData.RoleID = role.RoleID;    
        using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData));
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(URI, content);    

            //throws an exception if a 500 Internal Server Error occurred
            responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}


[LoginAuthentication, AdminAuthorization]
public class RoleController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost, Route("SaveRole")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Save(OmRole objrole)
    {
        try
        {
            await _role.Save(objrole);
            return Json(new { Success = true });    
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Success = false });    
        }
    }
}
```

**HTTP and Web Api**

The route `api/v1/SaveRole` does not seem RESTful. RESTful APIs are resource-oriented - a more natural way would be to simply issue a POST requets to `api/v1/routes`.

If you're using Web API 2, your method `rolesAPIController.Save` could be re-written to leverage the `IHttpActionResult` family of classes

```
public async IHttpActionResult Save([FromBody] OM_Role role)
{
    var result = await _role.Save(role);
    return Ok(new {ErrorMessage = result});
}
```

Also notice how you're returning a 200 OK response, even if the request failed. This is definitly not right. You should serve a 500 Internal Server Error instead.

Comment: Thank you first of all for the very quick suggestion. I am checking for `IHttpActionResult` **Question**: `async` is being used in BLL Layer. Although the `async` operation is already being done in BLL. Then do I still need to mark Presentation Layer Controller  as `async` ?

Comment: @Pankaj Yes, the code needs to be async all the way.

Comment: I saw the updated code: That says the code is unnecessary `var result = ((RoleResponse)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoleResponse>(responseBody));`   In this code I am DeSerializing the Object. May I request to suggest to proper way of DeSerialization ?

Comment: @Pankaj Not the code, the *cast*. You could simply do this: `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoleResponse>(responseBody)`

Comment: @Pankaj I added an example showing how I'd report errors, instead of using an empty/non-empty string.